# Shortcode created to check language not works

Tags: php, functions, shortcode

i need to create a shortcode to display a different Div depending on WP current language only when users are logout.

The shortcode is this one:

```
function coupon_box() {

$user = is_user_logged_in() ;


if ($user == false) {

    if (get_locale() == 'en_Us') {
    echo ' <div class="discount"><h3 style="text-align: left;">Is this your first order?</h3><p style="text-align: left;">Request your discount code for a value of 20 euros.</p><p style="text-align: left;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><a class="myButton" href="https://www.atremoplus.net/welcome-coupon/">Receive my code 
</a></span></p></div>';
}

    elseif (get_locale() == 'fr_Fr') {

    echo '<div class="discount"><h3 style="text-align: left;">C’est votre première commande?</h3><p style="text-align: left;">Demandez votre code de réduction d’une valeur de 20 Euros.</p><p style="text-align: left;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><a class="myButton" href="https://atremoplus.fr/bienvenue/">Recevoir mon code</a></span></p></div>';
    }

    elseif (get_locale() == 'de_De') {
    echo '<div class="discount"><h3 style="text-align: left;">Ist dies Ihre erste Bestellung?</h3><p style="text-align: left;"> Fordern Sie Ihren persönlichen 20 Euros Rabatt.</p><p style="text-align: left;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><a class="myButton" href="https://www.atremoplus.net/de/atremoplus-kaufen/">Gutscheincode anfordern</a></span></p></div>';
    }

    else {

    echo '<div class="discount"><h3 style="text-align: left;"> ¿Este es su primer pedido?</h3><p style="text-align: left;"> Solicite su código de descuento por un valor de 20 euros.</p><p style="text-align: left;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><a class="myButton" href="https://www.atremoplus.net/es/comprar-atremoplus/">Recibir mi código</a></span></p></div>';
    }
}

}

add_shortcode('coupon', 'coupon_box');
```

Is there something you see that is wrong please?

Thank you!

Comment: By the way it doesn't work

Comment: get_locale() will return a value like this `en_US`. Don't forget the second capital letter

Comment: by the way, what are you trying to do with your last else? Is it a error? Warning? Because it's missing get_locale and it's shown to logged in user.

Comment: That's for the last language, who is spanish. Actually it's not show to logged in users right?

Comment: I have edited your code, see below. Now backup language is English and shown to user who are not logged in. You could switch this to any language. If you want Spanish as backup language.

Comment: Is your backup/fallback language Spanish or English? What do you want to show users who don't use the languages you specified?

Comment: I have made two examples, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a shortcode you always need to return something. It's also good practice to make your code very logical and readable. Here are a list of PHP Logical Operators: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php
Complete List of WordPress Locale Codes: https://wpastra.com/docs/complete-list-wordpress-locale-codes/

Below an example as English as a backup/fallback language:

```
function coupon_shortcode() {
    $logged_in = is_user_logged_in();

    if (get_locale() == 'fr_FR' && $logged_in == false) {
        return '<div class="discount"><h3 style="text-align: left;">C’est votre première commande?</h3><p style="text-align: left;">Demandez votre code de réduction d’une valeur de 20 Euros.</p><p style="text-align: left;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><a class="myButton" href="https://atremoplus.fr/bienvenue/">Recevoir mon code</a></span></p></div>';
    }
    elseif (get_locale() == 'de_DE' && $logged_in == false) {
        return '<div class="discount"><h3 style="text-align: left;">Ist dies Ihre erste Bestellung?</h3><p style="text-align: left;"> Fordern Sie Ihren persönlichen 20 Euros Rabatt.</p><p style="text-align: left;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><a class="myButton" href="https://www.atremoplus.net/de/atremoplus-kaufen/">Gutscheincode anfordern</a></span></p></div>';
    }
    elseif (get_locale() == 'es_ES' && $logged_in == false) {
        return '<div class="discount"><h3 style="text-align: left;">¿Este es su primer pedido?</h3><p style="text-align: left;"> Solicite su código de descuento por un valor de 20 euros.</p><p style="text-align: left;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><a class="myButton" href="https://www.atremoplus.net/es/comprar-atremoplus/">Recibir mi código</a></span></p></div>';
    }
    elseif ($logged_in == false) { // Backup/fallback language is English and is shown only when user is not logged in
        return '<div class="discount"><h3 style="text-align: left;">Is this your first order?</h3><p style="text-align: left;">Request your discount code for a value of 20 euros.</p><p style="text-align: left;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><a class="myButton" href="https://www.atremoplus.net/welcome-coupon/">Receive my code 
</a></span></p></div>';
    }
}
add_shortcode('coupon', 'coupon_shortcode');
```

Below an example as Spanish as a backup/fallback language:

```
function coupon_shortcode() {
    $logged_in = is_user_logged_in();

    if (get_locale() == 'en_US' && $logged_in == false) {
        return '<div class="discount"><h3 style="text-align: left;">Is this your first order?</h3><p style="text-align: left;">Request your discount code for a value of 20 euros.</p><p style="text-align: left;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><a class="myButton" href="https://www.atremoplus.net/welcome-coupon/">Receive my code
    </a></span></p></div>';
    }
    elseif (get_locale() == 'fr_FR' && $logged_in == false) {
        return '<div class="discount"><h3 style="text-align: left;">C’est votre première commande?</h3><p style="text-align: left;">Demandez votre code de réduction d’une valeur de 20 Euros.</p><p style="text-align: left;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><a class="myButton" href="https://atremoplus.fr/bienvenue/">Recevoir mon code</a></span></p></div>';
    }
    elseif (get_locale() == 'de_DE' && $logged_in == false) {
        return '<div class="discount"><h3 style="text-align: left;">Ist dies Ihre erste Bestellung?</h3><p style="text-align: left;"> Fordern Sie Ihren persönlichen 20 Euros Rabatt.</p><p style="text-align: left;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><a class="myButton" href="https://www.atremoplus.net/de/atremoplus-kaufen/">Gutscheincode anfordern</a></span></p></div>';
    }
    elseif ($logged_in == false) { // Backup/fallback language is Spanish and is shown only when user is not logged in
        return '<div class="discount"><h3 style="text-align: left;">¿Este es su primer pedido?</h3><p style="text-align: left;"> Solicite su código de descuento por un valor de 20 euros.</p><p style="text-align: left;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><a class="myButton" href="https://www.atremoplus.net/es/comprar-atremoplus/">Recibir mi código</a></span></p></div>';
    }
}
add_shortcode('coupon', 'coupon_shortcode');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explication ;-). It works well right now ;-)

Comment: You're welcome :) I'm glad it worked.