# Shortcode returns escaped HTML tags

Tags: wp-query, functions, shortcode

To put things in context, I'm using Gantry on WordPress, which is bundled with Timber and Twig.

I have this code, basic, `make-your-text-bold` shortcode

```
// Add Shortcode
function bold_text_shortcode( $atts , $content = null ) {
    return '<strong>' . $content . '</strong>';
}
add_shortcode( 'b', 'bold_text_shortcode' );
```

and then in my twig particle,

```
  {% filter shortcodes %}
  [b] bold text [/b]
  {% endfilter %}
```

the expected result would be **bold text**, right?

or in HTML terms

```
<strong>bold text</strong>
```

but what I'm getting is

```
&lt;strong&gt; bold text &lt;/strong&gt;
```

I've read [shortcodes on the wordpress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/shortcode), [timber shortcode how-tos](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/wp-integration/#shortcodes), [Twig escaping](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#html-escaping), used the php functions

```
html_entity_decode("<code>foo and bar@!</code>");
htmlentities("<code>foo and bar@!</code>");
```

and [a combination of both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990422/how-to-prevent-wordpress-to-encode-html-in-post), but no dice.

I'm at my wit's end. I can't figure out where the escaping is happening. Made an account for this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you enable automatic output escaping globally? See: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html#escaper-extension

Comment: If nobody answers this question, than I will look when I'm at the office. In my time zone it's early in the morning.

Comment: Also, have a look at this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/317666/149484

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using single quotes if you want to include some HTML, also you need to return something otherwise nothing happens.

```
// WP Shortcode
function text_shortcode() {
    return '<strong>bold text:</strong> <a href="https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/318934/shortcode-returns-escaped-html-tags">See wordpress.stackexchange.com</a>';
}
add_shortcode('bold-text', 'text_shortcode');
```

Your WordPress shortcode would be:

```
[bold-text]
```

**Edit:** You don't need `html_entity_decode` or `htmlentities` only when you're doing something very complex or when you want to output some HTML.

**The Escaper Extension Twig**
You're using Twig, so you need to check if you have enabled escaping mode somewhere.

> ### Escaper Extension
>
> The escaper extension adds automatic output escaping to Twig. It defines a tag, autoescape, and a filter, raw.
>   When creating the escaper extension, you can switch on or off the
>   global output escaping strategy:
>
> ```
> $escaper = new Twig_Extension_Escaper('html');
> $twig->addExtension($escaper);
> ```
>
> If set to html, all variables in templates are escaped (using the html
>   escaping strategy), except those using the raw filter:
>
> `{{ article.to_html|raw }}`
>   
>   You can also change the escaping mode locally by using the autoescape tag:
>
> ```
> {% autoescape 'html' %}
>     {{ var }}
>     {{ var|raw }}      {# var won't be escaped #}
>     {{ var|escape }}   {# var won't be double-escaped #}
> {% endautoescape %}
> ```

Please bear with me, I don't use Twig, so I could only guide you on this.
So, in your case you would need to do something like this:

```
{% autoescape %}
    {% set hello = '<strong>Hello</strong>' %}
    {% set hola = '<strong>Hola</strong>' %}

    {{ false ? '<strong>Hola</strong>' : hello|raw }}
    does not render the same as
    {{ false ? hola : hello|raw }}
    but renders the same as
    {{ (false ? hola : hello)|raw }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

**Edit 2:**
Also see quote WP PHP Coding Standards below and see link: https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/

> ### Single and Double Quotes #
>
> Single and Double Quotes Use single and
>   double quotes when appropriate. If you’re not evaluating anything in
>   the string, use single quotes. You should almost never have to escape
>   quotes in a string, because you can just alternate your quoting style,
>   like so:
>
> ```
> echo '<a href="/static/link" title="Yeah yeah!">Link name</a>';
> echo "<a href='$link' title='$linktitle'>$linkname</a>";
> ```
>
> Text that goes into attributes should be run through `esc_attr()` so
>   that single or double quotes do not end the attribute value and
>   invalidate the HTML and cause a security issue. See Data Validation in
>   the Codex for further details.